# Recursive function TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list

Tags: python

```
def calc(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return [2 * calc(num-i) + math.pow(2,i) - 1 for i in range (1, num)]
```

when i run it, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list. How can i fix this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `calc()` returns a list (except if `num` is 1), but with `calc(num-i) + math.pow(2,i)` you're telling the program to concatenate a list to a float.